# Inserting specific fields into the database

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]

I have a structure like above and they are individual controls not a gridview so when a user fills the respective section only it should get entered into the DB but all the other fields also getting inserted.

```
  InsertObjectives(lblCommunication.Text, tbObj1.Text, tbRating.Text, tbStrength.Text,   cmn.Type, cmn.Contribution, cmn.ContributionRemarks);
        InsertObjectives(lblDomain.Text, tbObj2.Text, tbRating1.Text, tbStrength1.Text, cmn.Type, cmn.Contribution, cmn.ContributionRemarks);
        InsertObjectives(lblLeadership.Text, tbObj3.Text, tbRating2.Text, tbSTrength2.Text, cmn.Type, cmn.Contribution, cmn.ContributionRemarks);
        InsertObjectives(lblBehavior.Text, tbObj4.Text, tbRating3.Text, tbStrength3.Text, cmn.Type, cmn.Contribution, cmn.ContributionRemarks);




public void InsertObjectives(string lbl, string txtobj, string tbrating, string       tbstr,string strType,string strContribution,string strRemarks)
    {
        Common cmn = new Common();
        cmn.InsertObject(lbl, txtobj, tbrating, tbstr,strType,strContribution,strRemarks);

    }
```

Any help on this problem??

Comment: It is unclear what your question is. As long as you do not have data on all your controls but some, then your constructor should only pass the not empty, not null values. so what's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly, you can do it for the rest of the fields:

```
if (tbObj1.Text.Length > 0 && 
    tbRating.Text.Length > 0 && 
    tbStrength.Text.Length > 0)
{
    InsertObjectives(lblCommunication.Text, tbObj1.Text, tbRating.Text, tbStrength.Text,   cmn.Type, cmn.Contribution, cmn.ContributionRemarks);
}
```

OR, define this method:

```
bool CheckInputReady(params TextBox[] txtBoxes)
{
    bool inputReady = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < txtBoxes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxes[i].Text))
        {
            inputReady = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return inputReady;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (CheckInputReady(tbObj1, tbRating, tbStrength))
{
    InsertObjectives(lblCommunication.Text, tbObj1.Text, tbRating.Text, tbStrength.Text,   cmn.Type, cmn.Contribution, cmn.ContributionRemarks);
}
```

Comment: we can check for textboxes but how can we check for static label like communication or Domain?? i mean for which field he entered the data?

Comment: You don't need to once you have some data in other three textbox per row, you can just insert it into the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try check for empty string in Data Access Code and insert.

In

```
Common.cs
```

method

```
InsertObject(params1, etc){

   if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(params1){
//send to DB or prepare parameters
 }
}
```